# ROCR error: Format of predictions is invalid

Tags: r, r-caret

After getting my predictions from glmnet, I am trying to use "prediction" function, in "ROCR" package, to get tpr, fpr, etc but get this error:

```
pred <- prediction(pred_glmnet_s5_3class, y)
Error in prediction(pred_glmnet_s5_3class, y) : 
Format of predictions is invalid.
```

I have output both glmnet predictions and labels and they look like they are in similar format and hence I don't understand what is invalid here.

The code is as follows and input can be found here [input](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c8edf4qqvriqc85/sensor6data_f21_s5_with3Labels.csv?dl=0). It is a small dataset and should not take much time to run.

```
library("ROCR")
library("caret")
sensor6data_s5_3class <- read.csv("/home/sensei/clustering /sensor6data_f21_s5_with3Labels.csv")
sensor6data_s5_3class <- within(sensor6data_s5_3class, Class <- as.factor(Class))
sensor6data_s5_3class$Class2 <- relevel(sensor6data_s5_3class$Class,ref="1")

set.seed("4321")
inTrain_s5_3class <- createDataPartition(y = sensor6data_s5_3class$Class, p = .75, list = FALSE)
training_s5_3class <- sensor6data_s5_3class[inTrain_s5_3class,]
testing_s5_3class <- sensor6data_s5_3class[-inTrain_s5_3class,] 
y <- testing_s5_3class[,22]

ctrl_s5_3class <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 10 , savePredictions = TRUE)
model_train_glmnet_s5_3class <- train(Class2 ~ ZCR + Energy + SpectralC + SpectralS + SpectralE + SpectralF + SpectralR + MFCC1 + MFCC2 + MFCC3 + MFCC4 + MFCC5 + MFCC6 + MFCC7 + MFCC8 + MFCC9 + MFCC10 + MFCC11 + MFCC12 + MFCC13, data = training_s5_3class, method="glmnet", trControl = ctrl_s5_3class)
pred_glmnet_s5_3class = predict(model_train_glmnet_s5_3class, newdata=testing_s5_3class, s = "model_train_glmnet_s5_3class$finalModel$lambdaOpt")

pred <- prediction(pred_glmnet_s5_3class, y)
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The main problem is that `prediction` takes "a vector, matrix, list, or data frame" for both `predictions` and `labels` arguments.  Even though `pred_glmnet_s5_3class` and `y` look like vectors, they are not, e.g.

```
sapply(c(is.vector, is.matrix, is.list, is.data.frame), do.call, list(y))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

In fact, they are factors (which can be seen from e.g. `class(y)`), and `?is.vector` informs us to

> Note that factors are *not* vectors; ‘is.vector’ returns ‘FALSE’
>        and ‘as.vector’ converts a factor to a character vector for ‘mode
>        = "any"’.

We can convert both objects to `numeric`:

```
pred <- prediction(as.numeric(pred_glmnet_s5_3class), as.numeric(y))
#   Number of classes is not equal to 2.
# ROCR currently supports only evaluation of binary classification tasks.
```

Unfortunately, it produces a different problem which is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed explanation. I was able to use ROCR for 2 class with your help and try to figure out how to get around >2 class problem.